# retrieving localstorage data on load javascript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have this code that is trying to retrieve data from localstorage.  However, nothing happens at all when it is run and there are no console errors.

```js
    var score = localStorage.getItem('score') || 0;
    
    function save() {
    counter = localStorage.getItem('score', score)
    }
```

```html
<body onload="save()">
        <p id="score">0</p>
        <img src="popcat1.png" alt="Invalid" id="popcat1">
```

I don't know I'm doing wrong and I want the score not to reset on refresh.  Please tell me if there is a better way.

Comment: If you're saving something why are you using `getItem`? Shouldn't it be `setItem`?

Comment: Typo: you need to call `localStorage.setItem,` on the save method instead of `localStorage.getItem`

Comment: To make the page show the current score you have to read localStorage and update the paragraph innerText. To update the localStorage, you have to put it into local storage, by reading it from the page and updating storage with localStorage.setItem('score', <value>). It's difficult to help without knowing what you are doing to achieve each of these steps.

Answer (score 0):

Local storage is not a complicated thing. There are only 4 basic operations.

Set data in localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('name', variable)
```

Get data from localStorage:

```
localStorage.getItem('name')
```

Remove from localStorage

```
localStorage.removeItem('name')
```

Remove all from localStorage

```
localStorage.clear()
```

In your code, you need to setItem first and than you can get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `setItem` on save rather than `getItem`:

```javascript
let score = localStorage.getItem('score') || 0
function save() {
  localStorage.setItem('score', score)
  //           ^^^^^^^
}
```

For more information check out the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).